# Applying Themes in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, themes

I use ASP.NET C# in a Web Application Project (not web site).

I would like use ASP.NET Theme feature for my Web Application.

From the root of my project I am able to create a special folder `App_Themes`

```
Root/App_Themes   --WORKS
```

but I need have App_Themes folder in a different level, in my case:

```
Root/Cms/App_Themes    --DOES NOT WOEK
```

I notice that Visual Studio does not allow insert an App_Themes in a sub folder.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [Here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx)

You can keep your Web project's files in any folder structure that is convenient for your application. To make it easier to work with your application, **ASP.NET reserves certain file and folder names** that you can use for specific types of content

---

So, **Its not allowed** because App_Theme folder is a **Special Folder** for ASP.Net and it is used by the Asp.Net to bind the Theme to the page using it. 
When you specify a theme in the @page directive with `Theme="MyTheme"` it knows where to get the resources for the theme. 
Its the way things are arranged.

If you want to have in another folder then create a "cms" folder as you want and Place your resources in some other folder name anything other then "App_Theme".

Similarly u cant use other Folders like App_Code , App_data , etc.

Comment: Ok I understand, at the moment I create a App_Theme and add a folder (Theme) with a subfix CMS like root/App_Themes/CMS-MYTHEME/ so I can have a similar considered effects bypassing this limitation. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article in which someone managed to do it in .Net 2.0.

I am not sure if it will still work on not.

http://www.joeaudette.com/overriding-the-location-for-app_themes.aspx

Comment: i don't know if it still works or not as its dated back to 2006 but there also they couldnt defy creating App_Theme folder in root folder. They had to create that folder and the Theme resources in the folder and then in the Virtual path Provider they are replacing the Resource files with that in some custom folder. but still they couldn't make App_Theme folder a sub folder of another folder like "cms" in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your links, it seems pretty complicated and mostly a HACK to Asp.net. For sure I will test it and let you know thanks